# what's the problem with css br clear?

Tags: css

I stumbled upon this article
http://www.thefloatingfrog.co.uk/css/my-hatred-of-br-clearall/

When would one need to use that ?
Why is it evil ?
I don't understand the substitute syntax can you explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting clear to both with not allow other elements to float on either the left or right side of the element. The class below is an easy way to add this anywhere.

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

So when you want to clear something (that is, if you were to float the next element to the left, it would be below the current element and to the left, instead of left of it) you'd simply add the .clear class.

The problem with the following code is that if later on you decide that you don't want to clear everything after the 'something' class, then you have to go through your HTML and remove the br clear="all" wherever you have that 'something' class.

```
<div class="something">Cool content.</div>
<br clear="all">
<div class="other">Cool content again.</div>
```

Instead you could do something like this:

```
.something {
    float: left;
}
.other {
    clear :both;
    float: left;
}

<div class="something">Hi!</div>
<div class="other">Hi again from below!</div>
```

That way if later on you decide to float all blocks with the 'other' class then you can just remove the 'clear:both;' from the CSS once.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to post something snarky about you not reading the article, but when I saw that it was just a page of vitriolic rage with no explanation, I figured I'd answer.

It's because there are better ways of doing what you want to do -- namely, by using CSS in the way he does in the article, he has separated the semantics of the elements he's displaying from how he's displaying them.  Why is this a big deal?  Well, for one, he can more easily transform how his page looks when it's shown on different platforms (mobile, desktop) and media (screen, print, a screen reader for the blind), simply by editing CSS and not having to touch the document itself.  This feature of CSS is pure gold.

On the other hand, if you use a construct such as this, you put in a hard constraint about your document's presentation that sticks around no matter what media or platform you're dealing with.  What makes him so mad?  Because once a developer has come in before him and used `<br clear="all">`, he has to take it out in order to get the benefits I just mentioned.  That's why it's so frustrating.  One bad developer can disable a whole host of development scenarios for every other developer who comes after.

As far as CSS goes, I have to say that it's a very difficult subject to just pick up without reading all about how it works.  It's hard to explain how the `clear` attribute works if you don't understand [floats](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527330).  I had quite a hard time myself until I bought a [great book on the subject](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527330).

Comment: OK thank you and his vitro was fun to read :) I hesitate giving good answer to you or mrinject. I gave to mrinject because he had less point than you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that your markup describes the information, and the CSS formats that information. 
A dummy 
 tag to clear floats isnt semantic, as it's only purpose is for layout reasons. There are other semantic ways of clearing floats that keep this separation. As commented below but here for clarity this is a good resource for semantically clearing floats http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: it would probably help if you point out some of the "Other semantic ways of clearing floats"

Comment: Indeed it would apologies. The source I have always refered to as it's explained well is Chris Coyiers site http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Answer (score 1):

When you have floated elements, the parent element can't calculate it's dimensions effectively and sizes incorrectly. Other items that follow floated items may also sit out of position. By clearing an element at the end of your floats, you <strike>correct</strike> alter this behaviour.

**EDIT**

Actually correct is probably the wrong word to use as this is what is supposed to happen and using the word correct suggests it is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The author is just going off on a crazy rant about how the same thing can be accomplished using CSS on the DIV elements themselves.  He's saying that br class="clear" is unnecessary.

It's also not a good practice because it mixes content with presentation.  If a web designer wanted to re-theme the web application, he or she would need to modify the HTML to pull out all of the br clear elements, whereas if this was done as the author suggested, then the CSS files could be swapped out independently of the HTML, making their jobs easier and giving them one less thing to rant and rave about.

The rant is of course justified, as these simple, silly lines of code can actually cause a lot of headaches.